# When and why do you have to use DUT when testing a verilog module?

Tags: module, verilog

I just started learning about software test benches for verilog modules. I noticed that when the test bench calls the module, it puts DUT in between the module name and the sensitivity list. What does this mean, and why is it necessary?

Comment: Is this what you mean?

your_module dut (all_your_ports);

Comment: Which simulator? Where's the code snippet? Help us out here!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you instantiate a module, you have to give the instance a name. e.g.

```
serial_port user_terminal (port mapping);
serial_port debug_port (port mapping);
```

would instantiate the module **serial_port** twice, with one of them called **user_terminal** and one called **debug_port**.

In your case, DUT is an abbreviation for Device Under Test and is being used as the instance name for your module.

You might like to check out the [Doulos Verilog Introduction](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog_designers_guide/).